# Ending regex with a specific character on first appearance

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have several source codes that I'm applying preg_match_all on.

this is what I tried:

```
$lazy = file_get_contents("Some_Source_code.txt");

if(!preg_match("#method_(.*)\(int var0, int var1, int var2\)#", $lazy, $function_name))
        die("nothing here");

preg_match_all("#method_".$function_name[1]."\(.*\){1}#", $lazy, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

but the output comes like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => method_2393(int var0, int var1, int var2)
            [1] => method_2393(0, 0, 0)).equals(this.field_1351.getText().toString()))
        )

)
```

ok, what I want is $matches[0][1]. But
How can I stop it once it detects the closing parentheses ' ) ' just like the first one.

I can process the line after I extract it, but how can I do it with regex?
I searched the answers of similar problems but they were too specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the regex as

```
#method_".$function_name[1]."\([^)]*\){1}#
```

**Where you got wrong**

```
#method_".$function_name[1]."\(.*\){1}#
```

here you used `\(.*\)` where `.*` would match anything including the `)`

**Changes made**

- `\([^)]*\)` here `[^)]*` it matches anything other than `)` so that it ends with the first occurence of the `)`
- You can also use a lazy matching using `.*?` instead of `.*` which is gready and consumes as much as characters as it can

Comment: That's what I need. Well explained!... Thank you